# UK Visa has been refused for false document

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, weddings, fraud

[image]

I applied for a marriage visitor visa, to get married to my boyfriend of 2 years.

We met while we were students in the UK and have had vacations together in the two years but not in the U.K.

With the application I had attached an offer letter from a company stating that I have a job offer open starting 3 months later.

This however has been tagged as non genuine, although the company is registered and is run by someone I know.

How can I appeal to this?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89188/discussion-on-question-by-pri95-uk-visa-has-been-refused-for-false-document).

Answer (score 5):

> With the application I had attached an offer letter from a company
>   stating that I have a job offer open starting 3 months later.
>
> This however has been tagged as non genuine, although the company is
>   registered and is run by someone I know.

There is a difference between the company being genuine, and the letter being genuine. People submit falsified bank statements all the time - in that case as well, the company (bank) is genuine but the bank statement is falsified.

The rejection notice unfortunately does not give you details as to why specifically they considered it as non-genuine.

The main problem here is that you have been rejected for deception - which is a very serious thing for visa applicants.  Therefore, it is an uphill battle for you to turn over this refusal.

I would also make sure that any future applications leave no room for ambiguity as far as your documents are concerned, otherwise you may risk a 10-year ban.

Comment: Yeah, I'll be making a fresh application soon and I have requested for a specific offer letter with the contact information. I can also get the director to write me a letter confirming my position and he agreed to provide me with personal ID and company ID and registration information. Hopefully this helps. Thank you so much for your advice, I really appreciate it guys!

Comment: "The rejection notice unfortunately does not give you details as to why specifically they considered it as non-genuine." Of course it doesn't. They think it's a forgery: they're not going to give the applicant advice on how to produce a better forgery for their next application!

Answer (score 3):

On your next application, you will **likely** be banned for ten years. That will be a disaster for you because it may very well sabotage your future with your boyfriend.

The **do it yourself** boat has already sailed. Under the circumstances the only reasonable course left to you is to engage the services of a competent immigration solicitor to proceed with one or the following courses of action:

- reapply for the visa
- appeal on Human Rights ground
- challenge the decision via judicial review

Comment: Not really. Paragraph 3.6 doesn't apply to spouses of British citizens. If the OP gets married to her boyfriend, she should be able to get a visa.

Comment: @greatone Unless UKVI consider it to be a marriage of convenience, I suppose. Either way, this application hasn’t done the OP any favours in terms of travel history.

Comment: We are considering to get married in another country other than the UK, but this refusal remains a black mark on my immigration history, although the job is completely legitimate and so is the company. Not sure what to do at this point.

Comment: @Pri95 See a lawyer. Don’t risk getting into a serial refusal spiral.

Comment: @Pri95 demand to see document verification report. Challenge the decision through judicial review if needed.

Comment: @greatone I have not heard about this, could you give me some info about requesting a verification report? Thanks!

Comment: @Pri95 I don't expect you'd be able to get it, but you can email foirequests@homeoffice.gsi.gov.uk and ask how to make an FOI request (keep it short)

Comment: The examination of travel documents is undertaken by trained staff in RALON, trained entry clearance officers or managers or by the National Document Fraud Unit (NDFU) and the results of their examination will be recorded in a Document Examination Record (DER). **This DER must never be disclosed to the applicant or a third party**.

Comment: @Pri95 This https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/576713/Documentation-verification-v1.pdf explains the document verification process. And here https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/requests-for-personal-data-uk-visas-and-immigration/request-personal-information-held-by-uk-visas-and-immigration is how to make a Subject Access Request

Comment: Thank you all for your great advice, really got some good input here. We have decided to file for a judicial review, initiating with the pre action protocol, do you have any advice towards this?

Comment: @Pri95 You're now in the situation of getting legal advice from untrained amateurs over the internet. You should talk to an actual lawyer before you do anything like this.

Comment: Yes we've been talking to some lawyers, most of them gives off an incompetent attitude. We will finalise one today anyway. We're considering if this route is better or getting married and applying for a EEA permit.